# How to send an email using a template from within extension (from code)

Tags: wordpress, extension, email

How can I send an email using an email template that is already saved (id=68) from within the extension I am working on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
civicrm_api3('MessageTemplate', 'send', array(
  'id' => 68,
  ... other params - see api explorer ...
));
```

Comment: Unfortunately api3 explorer does not tell which parameters are required. I tried adding Message Template ID and Contact ID and From email and Receipient email but get an error message back `"error_message": "Could not interpret return values from function."` I then tried removing From email and get this error `"code": null, "error_message": "mail() returned failure", "mode": 16, "debug_info": null, "type": "PEAR_Error", "user_info": null, "to_string": "[pear_error: message=\"mail() returned failure\" code=0 mode=callback callback=CRM_Utils_REST::fatal prefix=\"\" info=\"\"]",`

Comment: Although the api3 explorer was giving error, the actual code worked using the four paramters Message Template ID and Contact ID and From email and Receipient email.